# I am unable to connect to my Azure SQL Database from my website however I can connect to it with SSMS

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

My connection string:

```
<add name="fxnzConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Server=tcp:fxnz.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=fxnz;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=vvvvvvvvv" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Are you accessing SSMS from same server as web application ?

Comment: No, I think it is in the Authentication area,  Stack Trace has this line  
   FXLL_GB.Account.Register.CreateUser_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\billw\OneDrive\FlooringXtra\GB WebPortal\FXLL_GB\FXLL_GB\Account\Register.aspx.cs:18

That is not the server it is deployed on, this is only happening on the forms generated in the account folder of the vs project

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant Azure services access to your database.

1. Locate your server.
2. Click on "Show firewall settings"
3. Set "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" to ON.

Comment: Thanks for that but that is set already, unfortunately I am at a loss, i have two other sites working well but this , no

Comment: After much looking through stack trace I noticed this line.